# textfield search Titanium not working

Tags: database, search, tableview, textfield

Coding a app with titanium sdk 3.0.0 and Im in the last phase before release and I can't get my textfield search to work. This is my code:

```
var customSearchBar = Ti.UI.createView({
                    height:44,
                    top:0,
                    width:320,
                    backgroundColor:'black'
                    });

var customSearchField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
                    width:220,
                    hintText:'search',
                    autocorrect:false,
                    height:28,
                    top:8,
                    textAlign:'center',
                    clearOnEdit:true,
                    borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
                });

customSearchBar.add(customSearchField);

win.add(customSearchBar);

customSearchField.addEventListener("change", function(e) {

    var db = Ti.Database.open("Mydb");
    var rows = db.execute('SELECT rowid,Name FROM Mydb WHERE Name LIKE "%'+customSearchField.value+'%"');

           while (rows.isValidRow()){

               var row1 = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                      hasChild : true,
                      title: rows.fieldByName('Name'),
                      color:'#000',
                      backgroundImage: 'background.png',
                      rowid: rows.fieldByName('rowid')
                  });

                  data.push(row1);
                    rows.next();
          }
            rows.close();
            db.close();
      });

var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
      data : data,
      top: '45dp',
      backgroundColor : 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
      style: 1,
});

win.add(tableview);
tableview.add(row1);
```